# Confused with scipy csr_matrix multiply

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, multiplication

Consider

```py
row_A = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2 ])
col_A = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
data_A = np.array([4, 3, 8, 9])
csrMatrix_A = csr_matrix((data_A, (row_A, col_A)),
                          shape = (3, 3))

row_B = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2 ])
col_B = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])
data_B = np.array([7, 2, 5, 1])
csrMatrix_B = csr_matrix((data_B, (row_B, col_B)),
                  shape = (3, 3))

sparseMatrix = csrMatrix_A.multiply(csrMatrix_B)
```

So the first matrix is

```
[[4 3 0]
 [8 0 0]
 [0 9 0]]
```

The second matrix is

```
[[7 0 0]
 [2 5 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

Why is A x B's result

```
[[28  0  0]
 [16  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]]
```

and not

```
[[34 15  0]
 [56  0  0]
 [18 45  0]]
```

Is `csr_matrix.multiply` not actually multiplying the full matrix?

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html), `csr_matrix.multiply` is a point-wise multiplication. It sounds like you're looking for [`csr_matrix.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.dot.html) for the matrix dot-production.

Comment: I see, this is just point-wise multiply, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html

I had been under the assumption this is a real matrix multiply.

Comment: You can use the `.dot()` method (as @jared noted), or you can use the `@` operator: `csrMatrix_A @ csrMatrix_B`

Comment: `scipy.sparse` was oniginally modelled on the `np.matrix`  array subclass, which in turn was supposed to look like MATLAB.  So `*` was matrix multiply, and element-wise required its own method.  Now there's a move to make it more `array` like, with new classes like `csr_array`.  `@` is now the preferred operator for matrix multiply (in all of python).  Hopefully the official docs corresponding to your `scipy` version have these details correct.